# How to verify EU COVID Vaccine QRCode Signature in Java?

Tags: java, qr-code, digital-signature, base45

Is there anyway to verify the signature of the EU Covid Vaccine QR Code and make sure the QR Code was issued by an authorized entity?

Comment: maybe https://ec.europa.eu/health/sites/default/files/ehealth/docs/covid-certificate_json_specification_en.pdf and https://ec.europa.eu/health/sites/health/files/ehealth/docs/digital-green-certificates_v5_en.pdf could help you (see `Trust framework and detailed technical specifications` under https://ec.europa.eu/health/ehealth/covid-19_en)

Comment: If you prefer source code, you might want to look at [these reference implementations](https://github.com/eu-digital-green-certificates).

Comment: especially https://github.com/eu-digital-green-certificates/dgca-wallet-app-android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/dgca/wallet/app/android/certificate/DefaultGreenCertificateFetcher.kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Gaetano Piazzolla** who recently wrote an article on how to verify Green-Pass QR Code Signature.
Here is the article link:
[Green-Pass QR Code Signature Verification](https://gae-piaz.medium.com/green-pass-qr-code-signature-verification-java-f742079cc88)

He also wrote another article on how to Decode the EU Green-Pass QRCode.
Here is the link of the article: [Decode the EU Green-Pass QRCode](https://gae-piaz.medium.com/decode-the-eu-green-pass-qrcode-using-java-b5654e55b0fc)

Note: you don't need to upvote, I'm just adding this as an answer so that everybody can benefit from these great articles.

Comment: Can you please add some summary to you answers as [link only answers aren't really a good practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/525172).